# how to set download preferences in watir webdriver for internet explorer....what is the code need to be done

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, watir-webdriver

I am using ruby with watir-webdriver.
when downloading a file with chrome,code is there for setting preferences.
What is the procedure for doing the same with internet explorer

i had tried same preference setting that worked for chrome. But it failed in IE.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
Watir.default_timeout = 90
prefs = {
  :download => {
    :prompt_for_download => false,
      :default_directory => "#{custom_download_path}"
                      }
}
$browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :prefs => prefs
```

IE version :10+
Platform : windows 7..

Answer (score 0):

You should ask yourself what you are really testing here. Beyond 'is the file available and served correctly to a download request', doing file downloads using different browsers starts to be more of a test of the browser itself than your website/server code.  This is the sort of test I'd do on a single browser to verify the download link points to the right file, and call it good.  For other browsers maybe just verify that the user can see the download link, and that the URL for the download is correct.   Or if you really need to examine the file itself, then get the link address, and just download the file with curl or something similar.

Comment: look into something like AutoIt for automating stuff at the OS level.  Webdriver (and anything that uses it like Watir-webdriver, capybara, etc) is limited to launching the browser, navigating to web pages, and interacting with the webpages themselves.  It can't do things like click on the options menu in IE (which AutoIt can)